# Looking for a particular fantasy series involving body swapping

Tags: story-identification, shape-shifter

I'm looking for a series of fantasy books which involve a character transferring his soul to another body every time he dies.

The protagonist is, I believe, the red-haired son of a general. He dies for the first time during a mission to a rival kingdom during which he is to negotiate the wedding of his kingdom's princess.

His body is then transferred to the hated adversary (I think a prince). The next time he swaps bodies, I believe, is into the body of a leader of a mountain clan...

Can anyone help me to find the title of this series? I read it about ten years ago and have been aching to find it again...

Thanks!

Comment: I remember a similar plot, the main character shows mercy to a witch about to be executed. She casts a spell on him, just as she is about to die. The spell causes him to swap bodies with whoever starts to kill him. Over the course of the 2 or 3 novels, he shifts in few different bodies, male and female.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the series is the Quickening trilogy by Fiona McIntosh. Myrren, a witch gives the power to Wyl Thirsk, the red-haired son of a general, as he witnesses her death. The series consists of *Myrren's Gift*, *Blood and Memory* and *Bridge of Souls*. There is a mountain king, Cailech, who he switches bodies with.

[image]

Comment: Whoa, that's great! Thanks KenM! That's it exactly :)